# Javascript - My values aren't comparing properly, any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to get a div that will become fixed when it is hit by the top of the screen and lose the fixed positioning when it hits the footer. I've tried to find the top and bottom of the div, the top of the screen and the top of the footer. I then compare the values but it does not work as expected. None of the value comparisons work at the expected time. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

(I logged the values so I could see if it was working as expected.)
...

```
        $(window).scroll(function () {                  // assign scroll event listener

        const elem = $('.sidebar-section');
        const sidebar = elem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var sidebarTop = sidebar.top;
        var sidebarBottom = sidebar.bottom;

        const footerElem = document.getElementById("footer");
        const footer = footerElem.getBoundingClientRect();
        var footerTop = footer.top;

        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position
        console.log("siderbar " + sidebarBottom);
        console.log("footer " + footerTop);
        console.log("currentScroll " + currentScroll);
        if (currentScroll >= sidebarTop) {           // apply position: fixed if you 
            $('.sidebar-section').css({                      // scroll to that element or below it
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '96px',
                left: '5%',
                width: 'auto'
            });
        } else if (sidebarBottom >= footerTop) {           // If the bottom of the div hits the footer in changes positioning
            console.log(hit);
            $('.sidebar-section').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 'unset',
                bottom: '0',
            });
        } else {                                   // apply position: static
            $('.sidebar-section').css({                      // if you scroll above it
                position: 'static'
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Tip: you can use `console.log("Bla bla", somevariable)` to have the variable logged without converting it to string. I don't think it's gonna help you here but it's good to know if you wanted to log an array or something like that. For example, you can log the entire bounding rect this way.

Comment: I cant't help in your code directly, I'm not really jquery. What I would suggest is to look at intersectionObserver, it's in fact easier to set up. At first, it seems "big" but in fact it's lot easier to implement than checking always scroll and it's not hanging the browser. Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API. You can check a header fix here: https://github.com/pierfarrugia/intersection_observer_header_fixed